# Security of launching files from program

Tags: c#, security, process, config, launch

I have a launcher app which lets the user select `exe` files they want to open quickly. To do this, they select the file from a File Browser, and I store the exe path in a config file. Is there a security problem with this? My concern is that some malware could alter the config file to change the exe file to a malicious executable and the app would then launch it. Is this a viable threat, or is it the case that if the malware can rewrite a file, it wouldn't need a proxy app to launch another file? I could encrypt the file, but I don't mind the user manually altering the settings via a text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store in your config file the Hash of the exe file launched and inform the user if the hash changes between execution.

To calculate the Hash of a file:

```
public static string ComputeHash(string fileName)
{
    using(FileStream st = File.OpenRead(fileName))
    {
         SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());
         byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(st);
         return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, but couldn't the malware also just replace the hash in the config file with the hash of the exe file it wants to launch?

Comment: Should be a malware that knows very well your application. I say, _targeted for you_. How this is probable or possible depends on your execution environment.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking of something application specific. It is a consumer app, so it could be popular (or could just go unknown). I guess one further way would be to hardcode a salt into my program that is used with your hash code. Whilst the code will be obfuscated, someone could find the salt if they really tried, but I think that would significantly reduce the appeal of trying to use my application as a proxy. Would that be a good idea?

Comment: Difficult to say. Everything you save on the user machine could be manipulated and compromised by a determined hacker. You could only try to give him a challenging task but you will never be _safe_.

Comment: I don't expect to be 100% safe, but just want to ensure it takes a bit of effort. Think I'll use the salt + hash method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are guessing right: if malware can change the content of the files on your disk you are already in trouble, as instead of changing the config file it can just replace the exe with another version or format the disk.